# How to get combined disc space of all files in a directory with help of du in linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs, du

I have many files in a directory structure. I want to get combined size of particular files which have name *demo* in it. I tried following approach :
"find -name *demo* -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch | grep total" 
But i now found that du is giving me combined space in set of 1657 files.
"OUTPUT"

"105M       total

101M       total"

(First total is of first 1657 files and next total is of next 1657 files). Is there any way I can increase 1657 to higher number or I can get combined disc space in the end?

Comment: Use find's exec option: `find -name 'demo' -exec du -ch {} + | tail -n 1`

Comment: Not working. Giving output in bunch of 1657 files. I want summation of all.